# ¿Cómo crear una lista de propiedades de dos lineas, key value?

Tags: java, android

Cual es la mejor forma para mostrar una lista con dos lineas por item en Android, es decir para mostrar datos como propiedades:

```
Key1
Value1
------------------------------
Key2
Value2
------------------------------
Key3 
Value3
```

Si el dispositivo está en forma horizontal se muestre en X columnas la lista de valores, repartiendo el width equitativamente, es decir 2 columnas 50% %50% 3 columnas 33,3% 33,3% 33,3%

```
key1      | key3
value1    | value3
--------------------
key2      |
value2    |
```

Mi idea inicial es usar `listview` si el dispositivo está en modo `portrait` y usar un `GridView` si se pone en `landscape`, ya que con gridView se puede especificar columnas y que los espacios se reparten entre si.

Como lo haríais o hacéis para mostrar un patrón de valores (clave: valor)

Comment: Si no caben todos los pares en pantalla, ¿cómo quieres que se desplacen en modo portrait? ¿De derecha a izquierda o de arriba a abajo? Misma pregunta para el modo landscape.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos de forma vertical en ambos casos, ya que si lo pones dentro de un scrollView lo natural seria usar scroll vertical
El orden de los items da igual, si es más facil de izquierda hacia la derecha y el que no cabe abajo empezando por la izquierda, o bien de forma columna "office" los que no caben empiezan a la derecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El final lo he podido realizar solo con el objeto gridview, inicialmente se especifica solo una columna con la propiedad `android:numColumns="1"` y despues por código en el create de la actividad se controla si el dispositivo se pone en landscape y asignar un número diferente de columnas

código content_main.xml

```
<GridView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="1"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
/>
```

Código Java para detectar el dispositivo en horizontal "landscape"

```
GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview)
 if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            gridView.setNumColumns(3);
        }
```